# How to have Python use more of my CPU?

Tags: pi-3, python-2.x

I have a code written in Python that takes about 9% of the CPU when ran. I want it to use more so it can run faster. To solve this problem, I tried multiprocessing, however, before writing a code for it, I ran the same program in two different terminal which created two different Python processes. However, instead of each taking 9% of the CPU for a total of about 18% of CPU, each take about 5% for a total of 10% CPU. How can I change that and have each process take 9% of CPU or have just one program take >20% of CPU?

Thank you!

```
    import spidev, time, os

# opens SPI bus
spi = spidev.SpiDev()
spi.open(0, 0)

#spi1 = spidev.SpiDev()
#spi1.open(0, 1)

ch0 = 0
#ch1 = 1

now = time.time() * 1000
data = open("test_plot.dat", "w")
#data1 = open("test_plot_1.dat", "w")

def getReading(channel):
    # pull raw data from chip
    rawData = spi.xfer([1, (8 + channel) << 4, 0])
    # process raw data to something we understand
    processedData = ((rawData[1]&3) << 8) + rawData[2]
    return processedData
"""
def getReading1(channel):
    # pull raw data from chip
    rawData = spi1.xfer([1, (8 + channel) << 4, 0])
    # process raw data to something we understand
    processedData = ((rawData[1]&3) << 8) + rawData[2]
    return processedData
"""
while True:
    if (((time.time() * 1000) - now) < 10001):
        data.write("%d\n" % getReading(ch0))
        #data1.write("%d\n" % getReading1(ch1))
    else:
        break

# http://www.takaitra.com/posts/492
```

Comment: It depends on what your code is doing. I don't think anyone can answer this question as it's written. If you're going for performance though, consider dumping Python completely.

Comment: I have uploaded my code

Comment: If this is meant to just read from SPI a bunch of times you are effectively limited to the speed of the SPI operation, which is relatively slow. `GetReading` will block the process until its complete so 99.99999% of this script is just waiting for IO.

Comment: Is there a way to get  rid of that 99.999% of the time? Because I tried print, it was slower, I tried sys.stdout, that was slower too. Writing to the file was the fastest that I could find. However, I haven't tried cStringIO, can that help?

Answer (score 3):

You have two bottlenecks here that are going to slow you down. First, there's the SPI, which was mentioned in a comment.  That takes a few clock cycles in each direction and will limit you some.  The second is writing to the SD card.  I expect that the second is more important for your speed. Disk writes are generally much slower than computations, and the SD card is even slower than disk.

If you just want to use the whole number of CPU cycles, try taking those out and see what happens. Of course that means you won't be accomplishing your task, so then you'll need to put them back in some other way.  A possible option would be to buffer your write-to-disk operations and have them trickle out in their own thread while the rest of the code runs.  This may or may not work - For example, you might over-run the buffer and crash.  You'll have to do some design and experimentation.

Comment: Is there any way of reducing those clock cycles? MCP3008's datasheet mentions that it takes about 24 clock cycles per sample. I suspect that even if I can reduce it to about 20 cycles per sample, I should be able to increase the speed substantially. So, how exactly do I write to buffer and then to disk? Any tutorials or something? Will creating a list of all the input and then writing it to a file once I am done with my data collection do the trick?

Comment: @Akshat Tripathi, what is your real objective? You seem focused on increasing CPU usage but I suspect that's the wrong metric for what you really want to do. Are you really trying to increase your sample rate?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I am trying to do. I want to get as many sample points per second as possible. Ideally, 200k samples/second with this ADC

Comment: @AkshatTripathi I don't believe that you can reduce the cycles for the samples via SPI. The protocol works by sending a *series* of rising and falling edges over the line, and that necessarily takes clock cycles. The only option that I see is to use multiple SPI buses in parallel on different threads / processes, but there's a limit on the number of buses that you can have on the Pi. Moreover, you'll need to understand how to design and write the parallel program, which may or may not be an issue for you. Python does have "multiprocessing" but it does NOT have multi-threading, just FYI.

Comment: @AkshatTripathi Continuing on the last part of my comment: The parallel I/O that I mentioned (as I envisioned it) would require multi-threading, so it could NOT be implemented in Python. There may be a Python-work around, but I don't know what it would be.

Comment: @Pi3-user-here A simple approach to increase speed would be to do what was suggested in a comment - Put all of the results in a list (in memory) and only write at the end of the process. I don't know if that will get the sample rate you want though. (You can probably estimate that from the number of cycles per sample and the Pi's clock rate.) At some point if you're trying to squeeze to the limit of the Pi you will have to go to C to control at a lower level. At some point, though, you're also asking more from the Pi than it can do.

Comment: So just go ahead and write everything in C?

Comment: before you spend any time rewriting you should profile your program to see where the bottle neck is. This is easy on python using cPofile. I think i/o is not constrained by the gil neither are the highly optimised modules such asnumpy.dot (which is much faster than code you could write in C) Analogue reads have to take an amount of time what is it for your chip?

Comment: Profiling before optimizing existing code is always good advice. For new design, you'll have to relay on understanding of principals as a guide. Regarding language, you should match what you use to the job. Personally I avoid Python unless there's a specific open source module that I want to use and cannot find in a better language. For low level data connects, I'd go to C/C++. Java's sometimes handy due to its relatively user-friendly threading model. I have tools in place that let me easily use all of the above in a single program. If you want a simple yes/no, however, I'd say yes to C here.

Comment: @Brick Thank you so much! I used C and got 140 KSPS, any reason why I can't seem to go to 200 KSPS? Is it because I am performing other operations like writing to a file?

Comment: Writing to file from the same thread as the collection definitely could slow you down. That's why I suggested - as one possible option - that you might do the output from a separate thread. If the collection and the write to disk are from different threads, then I doubt the write will slow down your sensor reading. You probably need to profile though, to get find out the slow parts to get faster than you have now.